How can I correctly specify the TypeScript type of a function taking an optional parameter with optional properties in a JSDoc comment?
When I have a function like
/** @type {(envVar: string) => boolean} */
const envToBoolean = (envVar) => !!process.env[envVar];

IDEs show its TypeScript type as specified.
However, in this more complex case
/** @type {(env?: { isBrowser?: boolean, isDebug?: boolean }) => import('k6/options').Options} */
export const defaultOptions = ({ isBrowser = false, isDebug = envToBoolean('DEBUG_K6') } = {}) => ...

the type shown is not as expected; instead I see
function defaultOptions({isBrowser = false, isDebug}?): Options

If I write the same function in a TypeScript file
export const defaultOptions = ({ isBrowser = false, isDebug = false }: { isBrowser?: boolean, isDebug?: boolean } = {}): Options => { ... };

type x = typeof defaultOptions;

the types I get are
function defaultOptions({isBrowser = false, isDebug = false}?: {isBrowser?: boolean, isDebug?: boolean}): Options

// when hovering over x
({isBrowser, isDebug}?: {isBrowser?: boolean, isDebug?: boolean}) => Options

However, I can't actually use a TypeScript function in a K6 script; even though they are supposed to be supported, I get an error message when importing functions from another module.
So is there a way to specify the type above using only JSDoc?
Some other approaches I've tried based on https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html:
/**
 * @param {{ isBrowser?: boolean, isDebug?: boolean }} [env={}]
 * @returns {import('k6/options').Options}
 */

/**
 * @typedef {{ isBrowser?: boolean, isDebug?: boolean }} DefaultOptionsParam
 * @param {DefaultOptionsParam} [env={}]
 * @returns {import('k6/options').Options}
 */

/**
 * @param {Object=} env
 * @param {boolean=} env.isBrowser
 * @param {boolean=} env.isDebug
 * @returns {import('k6/options').Options}
 */

/**
 * @param {object} [env={}]
 * @param {boolean} [env.isBrowser=false]
 * @param {boolean} [env.isDebug=false]
 * @returns {import('k6/options').Options}
 */

None of them change the parameters, but some inline the k6.Options definition.

for your second example, what type do you expect?

@Max I included the type TypeScript gives in the question.

Please [edit] the question to include a [mre]. After fixing the pseudocode in your question, I can't reproduce your claims — example TS Playground.
